# I want to know exact command of "find . -name '*.c' -or -name '*.cpp'" in Linux

Tags: linux, find, command

I'm studying shell in Linux these days. and I've had one question.

Please, look at below command:

```
$ find . -name '*.c' -or -name '*.cpp'
```

Exact command of above command is processed like below command?

```
$ find . -name '*.c' -and -print -or -name '*.cpp' -and -print
```

Answer (score 0):

You are combining different search expressions with the logical operator `or`.
Basically your command will find all files in the current directory ending with `.c` or `.cpp`and will print them to `STDOUT`.
For further info check the `man` page of `find` command.
Also note that this question would be more suitable to ask [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).